# What was Smith's proof of Smith's theorem on Hamilton cycles in cubic graphs?

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, hamiltonian-graphs, alternative-proof

In a short 1946 paper "On Hamiltonian Circuits", Tutte proved the famous result that an edge in a cubic graph lies in an even number of Hamilton circuits.

He attributed the result to his friend CAB Smith, but explicitly mentioned that the proof was not Smith's proof.

What *was* Smith's proof?

Comment: I find this a wonderful question, especially since it rests on an implicit assumption that proofs are *mathematical* objects and can be meaningfully non-isomorphic, a very important and modern topic.  Tangentially relevant comments: (0) an article on the "CAB Smith" in the OP is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cedric_Smith_(statistician)), (1) there should be people around who have known him personally, (2) the first constructive proof was given by Thomason via his 'lollipop-method', (3) the newest news on Smithian theorem is [this preprint of Pitz](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.07031).

Answer (score 2):

I am fairly sure that I once asked Adrian Bondy about it, who replied something along the lines of Bill Tutte having told him that the original proof by Smith was quite messy.

Comment: Thanks Tommy...and welcome to MO. Given that there is an algebraic proof (Tutte's) and two constructive/algorithmic proofs (yours and Thomason's), I wonder if Smith's was again different.